# Sending HTTP Request to PHP Function on Websever

Tags: php, android, web-services, http

I am currently building a simple Android app that makes a call to a simple php script on my web sever. I am fairly new to Android development. In iOS all I did was make a soap request but in Android I would like to make HTTP request since SOAP is not natively supported.

**What is easiest way to implement a HTTP request that goes to this PHP function in Android?**

This is my PHP script on my server:

```
function test($text1, $text2)

{

 $fullstring = $text1." ".$text2; 

 return $fullstring;
}

$server = new SoapServer(null, array('uri' => ""));
$server->addFunction("test");
$server->handle();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should see [this](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-use-httpurlconnection-post-data-to-web-server/139) ; this program sending Post request but you can change it to get Request and in sending you should send SOAP request String what u are following and u will get response

Comment: How would I make it go into the PHP function test??